# Creating my first Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, genetic-algorithm, biological-neural-network

Hey guys back again with a whole new project for myself. In my earlier posts I was getting use to programming to do certain jobs was rather easy to get use to but now I want to see what can be done in programming something more creative.

So I will be asking a series of questions related to algorithms. Have not a Scooby what they truly are or how to write one. But one that interests me is GA(Genetic Algorithms).

I’ve broke down what I will try and achieve but I need a start point and some programming (console c#) to get me on my way and thinking programmatically. Hope you enjoy the read and can help me on my way.

All living organisms consist of cells. In each cell there is the same set of chromosomes. Chromosomes are strings of DNA and serves as a model for the whole organism. A chromosome consist of genes, blocks of DNA. Each gene encodes a particular protein. Basically can be said, that each gene encodes a trait, for example color of eyes. Possible settings for a trait (e.g. blue, brown) are called alleles. Each gene has its own position in the chromosome. This position is called locus.

Complete set of genetic material (all chromosomes) is called genome. Particular set of genes in genome is called genotype. The genotype is with later development after birth base for the organism's phenotype, its physical and mental characteristics, such as eye color, intelligence etc.

**Outline of the Basic Genetic Algorithm**

1. **[Start]** Generate random population of n chromosomes (suitable solutions for the problem)
2. **[Fitness]** Evaluate the fitness f(x) of each chromosome x in the population
3. **[New population]** Create a new population by repeating following steps until the new population is complete
        1. **[Selection]** Select two parent chromosomes from a population according to their fitness (the better fitness, the bigger chance to be selected)
        2. **[Crossover]** With a crossover probability cross over the parents to form a new offspring (children). If no crossover was performed, offspring is an exact copy of parents.
        3. **[Mutation]** With a mutation probability mutate new offspring at each locus (position in chromosome).
        4. [Accepting] Place new offspring in a new population
4. **[Replace]** Use new generated population for a further run of algorithm
5. **[Test]** If the end condition is satisfied, stop, and return the best solution in current population
6. **[Loop]** Go to step 2

**Encoding of a Chromosome**

The chromosome should in some way contain information about solution which it represents. The most used way of encoding is a binary string. The chromosome then could look like this:

```
Chromosome 1    1101100100110110
Chromosome 2    1101111000011110
```

Each chromosome has one binary string. Each bit in this string can represent some characteristic of the solution. Or the whole string can represent a number - this has been used in the basic GA applet.

Of course, there are many other ways of encoding. This depends mainly on the solved problem. For example, one can encode directly integer or real numbers, sometimes it is useful to encode some permutations and so on.

**Crossover**

After we have decided what encoding we will use, we can make a step to crossover. Crossover selects genes from parent chromosomes and creates a new offspring. The simplest way how to do this is to choose randomly some crossover point and everything before this point point copy from a first parent and then everything after a crossover point copy from the second parent.

Crossover can then look like this ( | is the crossover point):

```
Chromosome 1    11011 | 00100110110
Chromosome 2    11011 | 11000011110
Offspring 1     11011 | 11000011110
Offspring 2     11011 | 00100110110
```

There are other ways how to make crossover, for example we can choose more crossover points. Crossover can be rather complicated and very depends on encoding of the encoding of chromosome. Specific crossover made for a specific problem can improve performance of the genetic algorithm.

**Mutation**

After a crossover is performed, mutation takes place. This is to prevent falling all solutions in population into a local optimum of solved problem. Mutation changes randomly the new offspring. For binary encoding we can switch a few randomly chosen bits from 1 to 0 or from 0 to 1. Mutation can then be following:

```
Original offspring 1    1101111000011110
Original offspring 2    1101100100110110
Mutated offspring 1     1100111000011110
Mutated offspring 2     1101101100110110
```

The mutation depends on the encoding as well as the crossover. For example when we are encoding permutations, mutation could be exchanging two genes.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: where did you hide the question?

Comment: We don't need an explanation of GAs in order to help.  Those who can help already know, and would rather not have to filter out the noise.

Comment: The question is how to get started and abit obscure but detailing an algorithm would be nice with some examples to get started. Im waiting on some books coming on algorithms but thought it would be nice if the community could help out for the time being.

Comment: `but I need a start point and some programming (console c#) to get me on my way and thinking programmatically` apparently that's the question.

Comment: ahh ok cHao, sorry for that buddy. Just detailing some of the starter points and how I would go about achieveing my first GA

Comment: @Garrith Graham: this is a nice example to start with: http://www.lalena.com/AI/Tsp/

Comment: thanks im already on most GA sites found a nice tutorial here: http://www.obitko.com/tutorials/genetic-algorithms/biological-background.php

Comment: I learn best tho from example and asking questions (dont ask me why but it works for me)

Comment: But SO is not a place where you ask "can someone hold my hand for a week while I learn how to program". You need to ask *specific* questions. So fire up Visual Studio, start your program, and when you're stumped, come back with a specific question.

Comment: im already stumped I dont even know what an algorithm is or how to write one the basis for the question.

Comment: You already have the algorithm. An algorithm is like the food recipe. It has stuff like "Mix the milk with the flour and stir". An implementation specifies the tools to use, the order in which you use them, for how long, and how to tell if you're done. The step-by-step list you have is already an algorithm. Now start implementing it. And if you have no idea how to build this program *at all*, I suggest you go find an example program that looks similar to what you want to do and start reading code.

Comment: Here's a google query: "example genetic algorithm in C#", that gave me this link at the top, it looks like a good start: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/btl_ga.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your explanation.

> **Outline of the Basic Genetic Algorithm**
>
> 1. **[Start]** Generate random population of n chromosomes (suitable solutions for the problem)
> 2. **[Fitness]** Evaluate the fitness f(x) of each chromosome x in the population
> 3. **[New population]** Create a new population by repeating following steps until the new population is complete
>
>    1. **[Selection]** Select two parent chromosomes from a population according to their fitness (the better fitness, the bigger chance to be selected)
>    2. **[Crossover]** With a crossover probability cross over the parents to form a new offspring (children). If no crossover was performed, offspring is an exact copy of parents.
>    3. **[Mutation]** With a mutation probability mutate new offspring at each locus (position in chromosome).
>    4. **[Accepting]** Place new offspring in a new population
> 4. **[Replace]** Use new generated population for a further run of algorithm
> 5. **[Test]** If the end condition is satisfied, stop, and return the best solution in current population
> 6. **[Loop]** Go to step 2

That already looks an awful lot like a program.  If you take that, and convert it to code, you should be about 95% of the way.  What you'll be missing is your "fitness function", which is basically the running of the solution + the criteria for success.  That varies per question, so we can't help much there.  But what it'd do is more than likely use the bits of the chromosome as flags or opcodes, depending on the complexity of the problem, and see whether and how fast the chromosome (ie: the current combination of bits/bytes/flags/opcodes/whatever) solved the problem.

Comment: does there have to be a criteria for success? Is there not a way you can programm "randomness" or "learning" seems cheating to me to give it a soloution?

Comment: If you already have code for the solution, you don't need a GA -- you can just code the solution directly.  But if you're doing this entirely for your own enlightenment, realize that computers don't cheat unless you program them to.  :)

Comment: And yes, there has to be some criteria for success.  Otherwise you'll be stuck with useless algorithms forever.  :)  The hard part is determining how to measure fitness.  Whether the problem was solved is part of it, but if there's a way to get points for being "close", then that'd be good.

Comment: Nature has the most basic success criteria there is, survivability. Nature doesn't throw all the gene combinations into a hat, and pick the one it thinks is the best, it just spawns them all out into the wild. Some animals are born with 3 legs, they don't survive for long, unless that for some reason is a good survivability trait in that region. That's just how real mutations work. What you need to do is quantify that "survivability rate" for whatever it is you want to use GA for. If you're using GA to do time scheduling, you need to quantify how much better one schedule is compared to another

Comment: Interesting its hard not to think grandiose and plug in all the measures nature takes for mutations and survivability or "success" im interested in Biology so it will be biology based, getting to as close as possible to the real world evolution would be my criteria.

Comment: Real-world evolution depends in part on algorithms not just competing with each other, but actively trying to suppress each other.  (In the real world, some critters eat others, some are parasites, etc.)  Emulating that may be considerably more complex than you think, and in the case of GAs to solve problems, is generally counter-productive.  (GAs could spend more bits trying to defeat each other than trying to solve the problem you give them.)  In the end you'd get not necessarily the best solution, but the most vicious.  :)